# How to open a file that is stored in a bucket connected to the google cloud VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to google cloud, and I need to run a single python script in a compute engine.

I opened a new VM compute engine instance, opened a new bucket, uploaded the script to the bucket and I can see that the VM is connected to the bucket since when I run the command to list the buckets in the VM it finds the bucket and states the script is indeed there.

What I'm missing out on is how do I run the script? Or more generally how do I access these files?

Was looking for a suitable command but could not find any, but I have a feeling there should be such a command (since the VM can find the bucket and the files contained in it, I guess it can also access them somehow). How should I proceed to run the script from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bucket's content is not attached to a volume in the VM. They are totally independent. With that being said, you first have to copy the python file from the bucket to your compute instance by using the gsutil cp command as below:

```
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/main.py .
```

Once you have the file locally in your compute instance, you can simply run the python file.

Comment: Thanks for considering the question, at start it didn't work because it needed one more argument, I added another argument (for where to save it in VM i guess) but there's another problem "No URLs matched: gs://my-bucket/main.py"

Comment: Finally it worked, this is what I did: `gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/main Desktop/main` and then `cd Desktop` then `python3 main` (worked only without the `.py` extension)

Comment: Great to hear that! :)